# Regex - How to replace a certain word given a few starting letters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string with me - "ct lungs, mediastinum". Now I want to do a `Regex.Replace` such that word starting with the letters "media" in the expression is converted to "chest".

So, the following strings should be converted to "ct chest no contrast" -

1. "ct media no contrast"
2. "ct medias no contrast"
3. "ct mediastin no contrast"
   etc.

I wrote

```
Regex.Replace(myString,@"\bmedia.*\b"," chest ")
```

but this is taking everything after "media" and "media" included and changing it to "chest". So, if I use the above on the given example then the words "no contrast" are lost. What can I do to only replace the word starting with "media" to "chest" and leave everything after that in the string as it is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could also use `string.Join(" ", str.Split().Select(w => w.StartsWith("media")?"chest":w))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = Regex.Replace( inputString, @"media\w*", "chest" , RegexOptions.None );
```

This means replace media + 0 or more matches of any word character with chest.

You may want to use:

```
\bmedia\w*
```

\b means word boundary, so you will only do it if the word starts with media

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I used!

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` is greedy, meaning it will try to take match as many characters as possible. You can make it match as few as possible by using `.*?` instead.

```
Regex.Replace(myString,@"\bmedia.*?\b"," chest ")
```

Answer (score 1):

In regex `\S*`  means non whitespace character zero or more times. So try with this one:

```
Regex.Replace(myString,@"\bmedia\S*"," chest ")
                                 ^^
```

You can switch the `\S*` into `[a-zA-Z]*` if you want to allow only alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `*` quantifier non-greedy by following it with `?`. This means it will stop consuming at the first word boundary it finds, not the last one (the end of the string).

Answer (score 1):

Without Regex, maybe something like this?

```
Dim tempList = myString.Split(" ").ToList()
tempList.Where(s => s == "media").ToList().ForEach(i => i = "chest")
Dim myString = String.Join(" ", tempList)
```